# Roblox Studio Анимации

Tags: анимация, lua, roblox

Проблема с анимациями, они то проигрываются, но коряво. Спустя пару секунд анимация начинает замедляться и персонаж просто не двигает ни руками ни ногами. Анимация бесконечная, стоит на 1x.
(если сделать анимацию конечной - ничего не поменяется)

```lua
repeat wait() until game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character

local UIS = game:GetService('UserInputService')
local Bar = script.Parent:WaitForChild('Background'):WaitForChild('Bar')
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local NormalWalkSpeed = 10
local NewWalkSpeed = 25
local power = 10
local sprinting = false
local character = player.Character
local Animation_id = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=12844678110"
R6_run_animation = Instance.new("Animation")
R6_run_animation.AnimationId = Animation_id


UIS.InputBegan:connect(function(key)
    if key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = NewWalkSpeed
        sprinting = true
        while power > 0 and sprinting == true do
            power = power - 0.03
            Bar:TweenSize(UDim2.new(power / 10, 0, 1, 0), 'Out', 'Quint', 0.1, true)
            wait()
            if power <= 0 then
                character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = NormalWalkSpeed
            end
            if sprinting == true then
                local playAnim = player.Character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(R6_run_animation)
                playAnim:Play()
            end
        end
    end
end)

UIS.InputEnded:connect(function(key)
    if key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = NormalWalkSpeed
        sprinting = false
        while power < 10 and sprinting == false do
            power = power + 0.03
            Bar:TweenSize(UDim2.new(power / 10, 0, 1, 0), 'Out', 'Quint', .1, true)
            wait()
            if power <= 0 then
                character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = NormalWalkSpeed
            end
            if sprinting == false then
                local playAnim = player.Character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(R6_run_animation)
                playAnim:Stop()
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Как не должно быть:

[image: Как не должно быть:]

Как должно быть:

[image: Как должно быть]